# Running a GUI app on linux, without showing the gui?

Tags: linux, user-interface, x11

I'm working with an api that requires an app to be started, the app runs a GUI on linux.

I need to punsh in some login information and then hide the app.

Is there a way I can go to the machine start the GUI and then hide it, log out, and have other users log in with out having the GUI shown, but still having the app running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look at Xvfb http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

it's a framebuffer version of X.
It will launch an X11 server without displaying it (useful with selenium for example)

Comment: That is really clever, but I actually need to punch in some login info before hiding the window -- can this be done with Xvfb?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at xdootool http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

To be honest, I never use xdootool, I just google a little.

Answer (score 3):

Xdotool can send input to anyb xwindow, including xvfb